# 'x' and 'units must have length > 0 error message when using ggplotly(). I tried converting to a factor. However, I still get the same error

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

Hi thanks for reading my question. Using the diamonds data

```
d1 <- diamonds %>% ggplot() + 
geom_col(aes(x = carat, y = price, fill = cut)) +
facet_grid(cut~clarity) +
theme_bw() + 
theme(strip.text.y = element_blank())
```

I am able to plot the graph, however when I insert d1 into `ggplotly()`I get the message:

> Error in grid :: unit(stripTextY$size, units = "points") :
> 'x' and 'units' must have length > 0

I tried converting cut to a factor, however I still get the same error. Does anyone have any advice? Thank you.

Comment: Having played with it a bit, it seems to related to the line `theme(strip.text.y = element_blank())`

Comment: If you delete `theme(strip.text.y = element_blank())`, the code works fine.

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen  Thank you to you both for that. Do you have any suggestions regarding how I can get rid of the text I had removed previously?

Comment: @UseR100185 Thank you to you both for that. Do you have any suggestions regarding how I can get rid of the text I had removed previously

Comment: I don't get the issue at all when I run the code, even with `theme(strip.text.y = ...)` - perhaps try restarting your R session or ensure everything is updated

Comment: @jpsmith I get the same error in R4.2.2, plotly 4.10.1, ggplot2 3.4.1 in a new session.

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen Hmmm strange - perhaps versions? I have R 4.3.1, plotly 4.10.2, and ggplot2 3.4.2 and [it seems to work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Trgs2.png) despite all my efforts to make it produce an error. Wish that was always the case :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug or version related, but for the sake of interest I went digging.

If you just want to strip out the text:

```
# load packages:
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

# comment out the strip text from the ggplot call:
d1 <- diamonds %>% ggplot() + 
  geom_col(aes(x = carat, y = price, fill = cut)) +
  facet_grid(cut~clarity) +
  theme_bw()  # + 
  # theme(strip.text.y = element_blank())

# use plotly_build to create a structure you can interfere with:
d2 <- ggplotly(d1)
fig <- plotly_build(d2)

# turn off the relevant text:
# start by exploring fig$x$layout$annotations - for me these labels appear at positions 11 to 15.
# set them to NULL
fig$x$layout$annotations[11:15] <- NULL

# and plot:
fig
```

[image]